# How to get all WebPart data / properties with PnP PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get all WebPart data/ properties on a SharePoint page using PnP PowerShell.

First I'm getting the page with:

```
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage "de/test2.aspx"
```

Then check the controls on the page:

```
$page.Controls

InstanceId                           Type        Title          Section Column Position PropertiesJson
----------                           ----        -----          ------- ------ -------- --------------
0e3f7654-f18d-4df5-9401-ae7f47c9ad7d PageText                   1       1      1
3dea7c8a-3eec-4189-b96b-81b2474aa6a0 PageWebPart Image          1       2      1        {"imageSourceType":2,"altText":"Dies ist der alternative Text.","linkUrl":"","overlayText":"Dies ist der überlagerte …
8c4315ac-6803-4753-83ac-18c9eb00cbf0 PageText                   2       1      1
604b4f67-0a14-4174-9945-ac53f3c7c6c4 PageWebPart Quick links    2       1      2        {"items":[{"sourceItem":{"itemType":2,"fileExtension":"","progId":""},"thumbnailType":3,"id":2,"description":"","altT…
f2da7eff-d8f8-48a0-a667-e258023af088 PageWebPart Button         2       2      1        {"alignment":"Left"}
4fa743ae-5899-4f29-9647-3c6f86438050 PageWebPart Call to action 2       2      2        {"image":{"zoomRatio":1},"button":{"linkUrl":""},"overlayText":{},"alignment":"Left"}
cf321c08-0b57-4d2f-bdc4-f3d6cd90d157 PageWebPart Link           2       2      3        {"linkPreviewComponentMode":0,"displayLink":true,"cachedMetaDataUpdateTimeStamp":1657099833637,"listId":"","webId":""…
c04c7873-dd7a-4fca-bfb3-722b8e4da916 PageWebPart Hero           3       1      1        {"heroLayoutThreshold":640,"carouselLayoutMaxWidth":639,"layoutCategory":1,"layout":2,"content":[{"id":"baf0df3e-3fa1…
06c21f0a-159f-4a19-bdb2-3444250bda0a PageWebPart Image gallery  3       1      2        {"layout":1,"carouselSettings":{"autoplay":false,"autoplaySpeed":5,"dots":false,"lazyLoad":true,"metadata":true,"swip…
```

The problem is, that not all components include all information of the WebPart in die PropertiesJson. For example the Button WebPart properties only contain the alignment info, but of course the button also contains a label and a link. Same problem happens with the Quick Links, Call to action, Link, Hero and Image gallery WebPart.

Is there a way to get all properties from a WebPart?

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Alex

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to get Web Part property:

```
Get-PnPWebPartProperty -ServerRelativePageUrl /sites/xxx/sitepages/xxx.aspx -Identity xxxxxx
```

For reference:
[Get-PnPWebPartProperty](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPWebPartProperty.html)

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved. If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.

Comment: The -Identity parameter is it the instanceId of the webpart on the page? for ex. I got the page through the Get-PnPClientSidePage command then got the webparts out with the controls property of the returned value in the prev. command. Is the InstanceId property of the control the value expected in the command you specified? if not where can I get this guid?